# How to insert np.array object in pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following pandas series:

```
s = pd.Series(dict(A = np.zeros(100), B = np.zeros(100), C = None))
```

How can I replace the last element with the object `np.zeros(100)`? In the real case, I have a very long Series and want to replace all None objects in a similar way.

So far, I tried:

```
s.fillna(np.zeros(100))
ValueError: invalid fill value with a <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

s.replace(None, np.zeros(100))
TypeError: 'regex' must be a string or a compiled regular expression or a list or dict of strings or regular expressions, you passed a 'bool'

s.fillna(np.NaN).replace(np.NaN, np.zeros(100))
TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'float'
```

Comment: Why would you want a `np.array` in a `pd.Series`?

Comment: `s.C = np.zeros(100)` works.  You may have to do it "manually" like this.

Comment: How is `s.apply(lambda x: np.zeros(100) if x is None else x)`?

Comment: @Abdou Great! Why didn't I think of this ... thanks!!